# Emacs android mode fails with "can't find project root" message

Tags: android, emacs

Since android studio is *very slow* for my computer I was trying to install android mode for Emacs.

Here is the relevant part in my .emacs file:

```
;; android mode

(require 'android-mode)
(custom-set-variables 
 '(android-mode-sdk-dir "~/Android/sdk")
)
```

Inside Emacs I invoke `M-x android-create-project`

Path :~/`test`

Package: `tk.erdem.test`

Activity: `test_activity`

When I run these commands I get

> can't find project root

error. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

An [issue](https://github.com/remvee/android-mode/issues/50) related to that was closed just last week.  Fetch a newer version from MELPA and try again.  BTW there's a special [emacs stack exchange site](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) too.